# How to bend a horizontally scrolling listview at an angle to display it as a rotating listview ?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontally scrolling listview with image and text in my app. I need to bend the listview at an angle so that the scrolling listview looks like its rotating. Below given is the image of the listview that I want which should scroll horizontally at an angle and enlarge the image at the center of the screen.

How do I achieve this? I have searched a lot through google and SO and could not find any related or appropriate results.

> [image]

Comment: use a custom Gallery view and override getChildStaticTransformation method

Comment: @pskink sorry but i have no idea what you are talking about.Can you suggest an example or try to elaborate?

Comment: read some Galleey tutorials, try googling for "gallery tutorial android"

Comment: @shivani can you share the code for the help for others?

Comment: @pskink i don't think the method you suggested will bend the  whole gallery view

Comment: @sivani did you find any solution

Comment: @VivekPratapSingh why dont you think? `Transformation` has a `Matrix` you can setup in the way you like

Comment: @pskink can you give me any example .. i am unable to do it

Comment: @VivekPratapSingh what have you tried if you are unable to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use carousel instead of listview to get appropriate result. Here you can check some examples

[Android-3D-Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)
[FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)
[3d-carousel-view-for-android](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/06/a-3d-carousel-view-for-android/#.UwMA32KSyL0)